# p:datatable rows by default editable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

so i have p:commpandButton which loads p:datatable on ajax see picture One.
I want p:datatable in editable mode by default (when it loads) see picture two

**picture One:** 
[image]

**picture Two:** 
 [image]

here is p:datatable :

```
<ui:composition template="/template/mastertemplate.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form styleClass="form" prependId="false">
      <p:panel id="analysisTheBudgetPenel" header="Analysis The Budget">
        <p:tabView id="scenarioTabViewId" style="width:850px">
           <p:tab title="Scenario One" id="scen">
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isApprovedBooleanId_checkBox" value="#{budgetAnalysisAction.budgetScenarioHescoProposalBean.abc}" />
              <p:scrollPanel style="width:800px; height:auto;">
              <p:dataTable id="budgetAnalysisDataTableId" rowIndexVar="index" editable="true" resizableColumns="true" value="#{budgetAnalysisAction.budgetScenarioHescoProposalBean.budgetScenarioHescoProposalListBean}" var="budgetScenarioHescoProposalList">
                 <p:ajax event="rowEdit" process="#{scenarioTabViewId:isApprovedBooleanId_checkBox}" listener="#{budgetAnalysisAction.testAjax}" />
// some columns
// closing tags of above
```

Comment: Are you aware of the *DataTable - Cell Editing?*  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf

Comment: @Daniel yes, cell editing is working on when i change values of fields  but here i am setting values in 'Proposed Budget' using javascript , see if i enter value in 'Enter Percentage textfield' after that i have to select column from selectbox then behind selectbox i am using javascript method which sets values in 'Proposed Budget' column after that user can save each row by clicking marks(save or cancel).

Comment: @mohsin azeem : You can use onload event in body tag, and trigger click event for datatable's pen icon :)

Comment: @RongNK can you guide me how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` tag has `onload` event that trigger event when page is loaded, so you can trigger click event to `pen` icon by:

```
<body onload="$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil').click();">
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used this event onComplete of p:commandButton

```
<p:commandButton id="isFinancialYearSubmitId" value="submit" update="panelGridId scenarioTabViewId:budgetAnalysisDataTableId scenarioTabViewId:selectColumnId scenarioTabViewId:isApprovedBooleanId_checkBox " action="#{budgetAnalysisAction.isFinancialYearOpened}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args); isFinancialYearOpenedOnComplete('analysisTheBudgetForm'); $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil').click();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching.
In Bean, you can get the p:dataTable component with ID and set EditingRow to true.

```
DataTable.setEditingRow(true);
```